# Mathematical indicator for the "flattness" of a curve?

Tags: math

I am currently working on a computer science project where I have to evaluate charts. The charts are simple lines in an x-y-coordinate-system, given by CSV files. the flatter the curve, the better for me. Now I am looking for an indicator for the "flatness" of these curves.

My first idea was to calculate the first derivative of the function and then calculate the average between two points. If this value is near 0, then the function is pretty flat.

Is that a good idea? Is there any better solution?

Edit:
[Here is a picture](http://tuhrig.de/wp-content/uploads/mathproblem1.jpg) as an example. Which curve is flatter between x1 and x2?

Comment: What do you mean by flat? is the line y = 100x considered flat, or is only the line y = 5?

Comment: oh sorry. i mean flat like y=5 (not like y=100x).

Comment: could you post a sample of your file ??

Comment: here is a picture as an example: [link](http://tuhrig.de/wp-content/uploads/mathproblem1.jpg). Now: Which curve is flatter between x1 and x2?

Comment: There are many ways that you could measure flatness, so you need to be rigorous defining what you want. Consider y=0.001*sin(1000000*x). This goes up and down very frequently, but only with amplitude 0.001. What about a function that goes up 10 then immediately down 10, but then is horizontal the rest of the way? Or a function like y = x that starts and ends at different heights?

Comment: 404 not found on your image, of course

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might consider using the standard deviation as a measure of distance from a perfectly flat line. First do a simple linear regression to find the ideally fitting flat line, then compute the standard deviation of the residues.

Comment: Doing a regression sounds like a great way to approach this problem.  Depending on the objective, the OP could consider doing a Chebyshev (minimize the maximum error) rather than least squares (minimize the mean error) fit.

Comment: alright, i agree so far. but why i need a linear regression? a perfect line for me, would be something like y=n (where n is 0,1,2...). couldn't i easily use y=0 for every chart to have compareable values?

Comment: Sure, if you only want horizontal flat lines, you can drop the linear regression and directly compute the SD. In this case, you effectively do a linear regression with the slope fixed to zero (equivalent to computing the mean of the values).

Answer (score 0):

if the values are all positive you could try calculating the integral.
So basically the surface below the line.

The lower the integral, the better. Just like you need it.

If you also expect negative values, you could basically do the same after changing the sign.

Comment: OK, so if I understand correctly you want to compare linear functions? So something like y=4x+3 is flatter than y=5x+3 ? What about y=4x+3 and y=4x+4?

Comment: y=4x+3 is equal to y=4x+4. and i just interested in part of the line between two points, not in whole function

Comment: I just saw your example. I agree with @thiton; calculating the standard deviation of the distances of each of the data points to a regression sounds good to me.

Answer (score 0):

If the quickness of change is important to the answer (that is, many small zig-zags are considered flatter than a gradual rise), the slope of the autocorrelation function might be interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Compare `max(abs(d))` where d is the (numerical) derivative of the curve. That'll give you how steep the curve is compared to the flat curve (y = CONSTANT), but won't tell you how far away from the flat curve you'll get.

Answer (score 0):

The peakedness of a statistical distribution is called "kurtosis".

Kurtosis = [[E[(mu-x)^4]]/[E[(mu-x)^2]]^2]-3

mu = average value of x in the population
E[y] = the expected value of y

Since this is usually used with probability functions, I would suggest you divide all values in the curve by the area under it.

Answer (score -1):

1.First apply the linear regression to find the ideally fitting flat line
2.Measure the least square of the residues.